# Value of dynamic UI input lost every time main input change

Tags: shiny

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::titlePanel("Dynamic UI"),
    shiny::sidebarLayout(
        shiny::sidebarPanel(width = 2,
        shiny::numericInput("num", "Number of input", value=1, min=1, max=7),
        htmltools::hr(style = "border-top: 5px dashed skyblue"),
        shiny::uiOutput("out")
        ),
        shiny::mainPanel()
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$out <- shiny::renderUI({
          lapply(1:input$num, function(i) {
            htmltools::div(
                htmltools::tags$h4(paste0("Input group: ",i)),
                shiny::numericInput(paste0("size", i),
                    label = "size",
                    value = 3, min = 1, max = 8
                ),
                shiny::numericInput(paste0("inc", i),
                    label = "incidence",
                    value = 1, min = 1, max = 8
                ),
                htmltools::hr(style = "border-top: 2px dashed skyblue")
            )
        })

    })

}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I created an example of app that dynamically create multiple numeric input depending on other input(**Number of input** here).
Now when **Number of input**  value changes, all the input value that are dynamically created is reset.
I know that because server side creating these input every time **Number of input** changes.
But, are there any way/trick so dynamic input value will remain unchanged when user change the **Number of input**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `react<-reactiveValues()` to have saved values.

Use `observeEvent(input$num, {})` to save input values in `react` values.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::titlePanel("Dynamic UI"),
  shiny::sidebarLayout(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                        shiny::numericInput("num", "Number of input", value=1, min=1, max=7),
                        htmltools::hr(style = "border-top: 5px dashed skyblue"),
                        shiny::uiOutput("out")
    ),
    shiny::mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  react <- reactiveValues(
    S=list(),
    I=list()
  )
  
  output$out <- shiny::renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$num, function(i) {
      input_size<- isolate(input[[paste0("size", i)]])
      input_inc <- isolate(input[[paste0("inc",  i)]])
      
      if (is.null(input_size)){
        input_size<-3
      }
      if (is.null(input_inc)){
        input_inc<-1
      }      
      
      htmltools::div(
        htmltools::tags$h4(paste0("Input group: ",i)),
        shiny::numericInput(paste0("size", i),
                            label = "size",
                            value = input_size , min = 1, max = 8
        ),
        shiny::numericInput(paste0("inc", i),
                            label = "incidence",
                            value =  input_inc, min = 1, max = 8
        ),
        htmltools::hr(style = "border-top: 2px dashed skyblue")
      )
    })
    
  })
  observeEvent(input$num, {    
    i <- input$num
    react$S[i]<- input[[paste0("size", i)]]
    react$I[i]<- input[[paste0("inc", i)]]
  },ignoreNULL = TRUE,    ignoreInit = TRUE
  )
  
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works. It also creates a new **problem** though.  When I try to type the number in the input field, the cursor disappeared after I type one digit. If  I have to type a big number that be bad user experience. Any solution for that?

Comment: `isolate()` added for input : `isolate(input[[paste0("size", i)]])`  :)

Comment: I mean : `Isolate()` fix your problem, on my R Shiny at least.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. `isolate()` indeed solved the problem. This answers my original question, so I will  accept the answer. Since you are here and you have expertise in dynamic input, I would ask  one more question if you can help me. 
lets say I input 3 in *Number of input* and  on input group:3 , I changed the size to 5.  
Now I change the *Number of input* to 2.  Input group: 3 is not available in UI now, But  if I print `input$size3` it still show the value 5. I was expecting NULL. Bcz `input$size3` does not exist in UI at this point. How to solve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the end of `ObserveEvent()` you could add `react$S<-react$S[1.. input$num]`: "get from one to number input$num".

Comment: And add  `input[[paste0("inc",  i+1)]] <- NULL`  in `ObserveEvent()`.